# Создание страницы для модели в RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mvc, haml

Имеется модель `Session` у которой связь Один-ко-многим с `Suggestions`, т.е. предложениями. У сессии много предложений. Сделал отдельную страничку `list_sug.html.haml`, в которой имеется список всех предложений по данной сессии. Сделал ради удобства. Но не могу на эту страничку попасть. В `routes.rb` прописал:

```
resources :sessions do
  get :list_sug
end
```

В `show.html.haml` в `session` добавил строку:

`= link_to session_list_sug_url(:session_id => @session.id)`

В контроллере добавил:

```
def list_sug
  @session = Session.find(params[:session_id])
end
```

И вот проблема в том, что на страничке сессии внизу светится ссылка

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/sessions/2/list_sug
```

при этом, если на нее навести/нажать, то она идет на `/sessions/2`, а если вручную ввести вышеуказанную ссылку, то он попадает на нужную страничку с предложениями. Почему так происходит и как это возможно поправить?

Answer (score 1):

В маршрутах:

```
resources :sessions do
  member {get :list_sug}
end
```

Ссылка:

```
= link_to 'Посмотреть список, например', session_list_sug_path(@session)
```

Экшн контроллера:

```
def list_sug
  @session = Session.find(params[:id])
end
```

Про `member` [тут](http://maxopka.su/2015/06/04/rails-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-resources-collection-member/)

Answer (score 0):

*Итого, симптом:* в **тексте** ссылки вы получили правильный маршрут, а в **адресе** что-то не то.

А теперь как так вышло. У [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) (если забыть о втором хэше) есть две формы вызова.

1. **Без блока** (`text, *url_args`), где первый аргумент это текст ссылки, а все последующие скармливаются [`url_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for)
2. **С блоком** (`*url_args, &block`), где *все аргументы* (кроме блока) передаются [`url_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for), а выведенное блоком становится содержимым тега `<a>`

И у вас сложилась крайне смешная ситуация. Вы использовали **первую форму**. И [`url_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for) получил *пустой список аргументов* (`[]`), то есть, указание **взять все параметры по умолчанию**, и берутся они... из **текущей страницы**. *О-ой!*

Выдайте ему содержимое ссылки и всё станет на место. Любым из двух способов:

```
= link_to "Предложения", путь

= link_to путь do
  %i.fa.fa-list- # Произвольная разметка, для примера значок из FontAwesome
```